# How to return the elements in the array that the variable falls between

Tags: ruby

I have a unique sorted array: `[2,4,6,8,10]`.

I have a variable called `i`. If `i` is `5`, I want to return the elements in the array that `5` falls between. In this case `[4,6]`. If `i` is `8`, then `[8,10]`.

How should I go about this?

I've tried with `partition`, to some extent. If `i` happens to be a number directly equal to one of the values in the array. This seems to work:

```
a=[2,4,6,8,10]
i = 6
a.partition { |v| v < i }.max[0..1] # returns [6,8]
```

However, if `i` is a number not directly equal to any of the values in the array. For example `5`, it gets a little trickier.

I got it working for the last case:

```
a=[2,4,6,8,10]
i = 5
partition = a.partition { |v| v < i }
[].tap { |a| a << partition[0].max; a << partition[1].min } # returns [6,8]
```

While this works, I am looking to see if there is a better way to write this logic.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: Seems like simple iteration with a comparison against the next element (if available).

Comment: Yea array is sorted

Comment: Your title and question state that you want to return the first element meeting your conditions, but your examples indicate you want to return two elements. Which is it?

Comment: Expected are from the examples. I changed the title to be consistent to the expectation

Comment: When code works and you want to know "if there is a better way", you should look at asking on [codereview.se] instead of [so].

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It should be faster than the previous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
val = 5
a = [2,4,6,8,10] # assuming it's sorted
a.slice(a.rindex {|e| e <= val}, 2)
```

It doesn't account for the case when the lookup value is equal or bigger the last element of the array. I'd probably append a nil element for this, if that would be appropriate for the problem.

Comment: That will return `6`. In this case, if `val` is `5`, result should return `[4,6]`

Comment: With your new edit. If you change `val` to `3`. Result returns as `[4,6]`. Result should be `[2,4]`

Comment: With your new edit! Sweet. Definitely better that my solution!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
def mind_the_gap(arr, n)
  arr.each_cons(2).find { |l,u| l <= n && n < u }
end

arr = [2,4,6,8,10]
mind_the_gap(arr, 5)  #=> [4,6]
mind_the_gap(arr, 8)  #=> [8,10]
mind_the_gap(arr, 1)  #=> nil
mind_the_gap(arr, 10) #=> nil
```

If you don't want the last two examples to return `nil`, you could change the method as follows.

```
def mind_the_gap(arr, n)
  rv = arr.each_cons(2).find { |l,u| l <= n && n < u }
  return rv unless rv.nil?
  n < arr.first ? :low : :high
end

mind_the_gap(arr, 5)  #=> [4,6]
mind_the_gap(arr, 8)  #=> [8,10]
mind_the_gap(arr, 1)  #=> :low
mind_the_gap(arr, 10) #=> :high
```

Another way is to use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

```
def mind_the_gap(arr, n)
  a = arr.slice_when  { |l,u| l <= n && n < u }.to_a
  return [a.first.last, a.last.first] unless a.size == 1
  n < arr.first ? :low : :high
end

mind_the_gap(arr, 5)  #=> [4,6]
mind_the_gap(arr, 8)  #=> [8,10]
mind_the_gap(arr, 1)  #=> :low
mind_the_gap(arr, 10) #=> :high
```

Comment: I like this answer, but your slice_when example has a syntax error, you left in the `rv` from the previous examples.

Comment: Thanks, @philomony. I confess that was not the only error. I think it's OK now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for elements inside a sorted array, the "better way" probably involves [`bsearch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) or [`bsearch_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index).

The second element in the pair is the first element in the array that is greater than your variable, so `bsearch_index` can return it directly. You need to check it isn't `nil` or `0` before returning the found element and the previous one :

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

def find_surrounding_pair(array, element)
  second_index = array.bsearch_index { |x| x > element }
  array[second_index - 1, 2] if second_index && second_index > 0
end

puts find_surrounding_pair(a, 1).nil?
puts find_surrounding_pair(a, 2) == [2, 4]
puts find_surrounding_pair(a, 7) == [6, 8]
puts find_surrounding_pair(a, 8) == [8, 10]
puts find_surrounding_pair(a, 12).nil?
#=> true * 5
```

The complexity of this method should be `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good use to check for the inclusion in a range:

```
a = [2,4,6,8,10]
b = 5
a.each_cons(2).select { |i, j| (i .. j) === b }
# => [[4, 6]]
```

It's not clear exactly what you mean by "falls between". In the code above `8` would fall between two sets of numbers:

```
b = 8
a.each_cons(2).select { |i, j| (i .. j) === b }
# => [[6, 8], [8, 10]]
```

if the test is `i <= b <= j`. If it's `i <= b < j` then use `...` instead of `..`:

```
a.each_cons(2).select { |i, j| (i ... j) === b }
# => [[8, 10]]
```

I'm not a big fan of using `...` but it simplifies the code.

From the [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html) documentation:

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

You could change that to:

```
a.each_cons(2).select { |i, j| i <= b && b <= j }
```

or:

```
a.each_cons(2).select { |i, j| i <= b && b < j }
```

if those work better for your mind. Using a Range is a little slower, but not radically so.